# Dispatcher.Invoke working in vs2010 but giving error in vs2008

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, compiler-errors, dispatcher

I have to submit my WPF project tomorrow morning; it is running perfectly in VS 2010 but giving error in VS 2008 (.NET 3.5 in both case) using C#.

I am using a timer using `Dispatcher.Invoke` but in VS 2008 it is giving error :

> Error 163
>   The best overloaded method match for `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.Delegate)` has some invalid argument.

The below code is giving the error:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // ANY ACTIONS HERE
    .. some task
}), null);
```

The code **must** work in VS 2008.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like the VS 2008 build is targeting .NET 3.0, not 3.5.  The [overload you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) was added in .NET 3.5, and the error message suggests that .NET 3.0 is being found.

You could easily rework the call to work using the 3.0 overload via:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
   {
      // ...some task
   }));
```

Comment: Thanks a Million , you saved me sir. Actually i did same but forget to remove null. Now its working fine . Please do one more favor, refer me a good book on threading , once again thanks a lot

Comment: @NidhiSharma You can read my blog for some intro stuff http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/  It's .NET 4 based, though.  I'd really recommend learning it from .NET 4+, though, as all the new features are much better than the old APIs